# Showing different php version on CLI and browser

Tags: 20.04, php, alternative

I have 3 `php` installed in my local but after installing `php8.1` i won't be able to change it for browser it is always showing old one.

I have tried with below command to change but nothing changed as per my expectation.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1

set PATH="/usr/bin/php8.1:$PATH"
```

in command line it show 8.1 version where in browser it show 7.4

Answer (score 2):

The PHP module used by your Apache server (and thus, the one shown "in the browser") is set in Apache configuration.

Depending on how you installed them, you can try something like

```
a2dismod php7.4
a2enmod php8.1
```

this will disable your old 7.4 module and enable the 8.1 version. You then have to reload Apache for the changes to take.

If it doesn't work, just invert the commands to re-enable your 7.4:

```
a2dismod php8.1
a2enmod php7.4
```

Be aware though, that depending on how you installed the modules (from source? from a `.deb` package?) the above might not work. If you can give more information about your Ubuntu version and how you installed the extra PHP versions, that'd help give more precise answers.

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.1` This was worked